# cannot update bokeh plots in heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, bokeh

I am creating a Heroku app with bokeh plots to be updated with a user input. When I run my python code, I see that the plots are updated in my local directory but on the Heroku app nothing changes. Here is the relative part of my app.py:

```
def graph(sym,yr,month):
    response=requests.get(some_link)
    data=response.json()
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=400)
    x_axis=[i for i in range(len(df.values))]
    p.line(x_axis,df['4. close'].iloc[::-1], line_width=2)
    output_file('templates\image.html')
    save(p)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index_lulu():
    return render_template('stockticker.html')

@app.route('/static/<path:path>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(os.path.join('static', path))

@app.route('/image.html',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def hello3():
    symbol=request.form['symbol_lulu']
    year=request.form['year_lulu']
    month=request.form['month_lulu']
    graph(symbol,year,month)
    return render_template('image.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

stockticker.html takes inputs of symbol, year, month. When I run app.py on terminal, image.html keeps getting updated but when I deploy it on Heroku, it always displays the same plot. I'm very new to this field, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that your immediate issue is related to the path names you're using. Check your logs to see if there are any interesting error messages there.

But even if you get that working it probably won't do what you expect. Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it will be lost the next time your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). You can't save files to the filesystem and expect them to stay there.

Heroku's [official recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) is to use a third-party service like Amazon S3 to store user uploads, dynamically-generated files, etc. This is also a good place for regular static files.

(In this instance, since you're creating the file each time the view loads, you might be able to get it working. But it's probably more efficient to cache the generated image for a certain amount of time, and you can't do that reliably on Heroku's filesystem.)